# how to read multiple PDFs in Python

Tags: python, pypdf

When I am trying to read and print contents of multiple PDFs in a folder in Python, I've been getting this error.  I could not sort it out.  Please help me.

pdfFileObj = open(fp, 'rb')
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Mr praveen.pdf'

This is my code

```
import PyPDF2
import os
path = r'/root/Desktop/temp_dir'     #path of folder containing several PDFs
for fp in os.listdir(path):
  pdfFileObj = open(fp, 'rb')

  pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj)
  print(pdfReader.numPages)

  for i in range(0,pdfReader.getNumPages()):
  ` data+= pdfReader.getPage(i).extractText()

  print data                  #(pageObj.extractText())
  pdfFileObj.close()
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the names returned from `os.listdir(path)` are only the filenames you have to `os.path.join(path, fp)` them with the directory name:

```
path = r'/root/Desktop/temp_dir'     #path of folder containing several PDFs
for fp in os.listdir(path):
    pdfFileObj = open(os.path.join(path, fp), 'rb')
```

Either that or do `os.chdir(path)` before the loop but that can cause problems elsewhere in programs so it is most of the time better to deal with full path names.

Comment: Sir eventhough I changed the code as     import PyPDF2
import os
path = '/root/Desktop/temp_dir/'
for fp in os.listdir(path):
  os.path.join(path,fp)
  with open(fp,'r') as pdfFileObject:
   pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObject)
   count = pdfReader.numPages
   for i in range(count):
     page = pdfReader.getPage(i)
     data = page.extractText()
   print data
   w = data.split()

Comment: You put it in the wrong place. The right place is `with open(os.path.join(path,fp),'r') as pdfFileObject:`.

Comment: when running the code to write password protected PDF in a location, I got this error  "raise utils.PdfReadError("Unable to find 'endstream' marker after stream at byte %s." % utils.hexStr(stream.tell())) PyPDF2.utils.PdfReadError: Unable to find 'endstream' marker after stream at byte 0xa721."

Comment: import PyPDF2,os
output = PyPDF2.PdfFileWriter()
input_stream = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(open("/root/Desktop/temp_dir/Mr praveen.pdf", "rb"))

for i in range(0, input_stream.getNumPages()):
        output.addPage(input_stream.getPage(i))

outputstream = open("/root/Desktop/name.pdf", "wb")
# Set user and owner password to pdf file
output.encrypt("mani", use_128bit=True)
output.write(outputstream)
outputStream.close()

Comment: Please help Sir

Answer (score 0):

You must pass full path to `open()` something like this:

```
open(path + "/" + fp , 'rb')
```